# Update last entries of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I have the following dataframes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], 
                   'results': ['Rick', 'Patram', 'Pulis', 'Marie', 'Landon' ]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['A', 'A', 'A'], 
                   'results': ['John', 'Peter', 'Anne']})
```

I need to make an update to the df with respect to the df2, depending on the number of entries that I have I must eliminate the last ones of the df and add the ones of the df2, in this example, for example I need to eliminate the last 3 of the df and add the 3 of the df2, being as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], 
                   'results': ['Rick', 'Patram', 'John', 'Peter', 'Anne']})
```

any suggestions? I tried indexing the users and with the update method but without good results.

Comment: What is the significance of `'A'` here? Is it just a filler value, or can it change and change the result?

Comment: can be changing, then the user can be B, C, etc.

Comment: and then what should the output be? You haven't said anything of it

Comment: the output for the example is df...

Comment: But you haven't shown what happens if the first column changes! That's why I asked, very specifically, if it was a constant value and whether it had any bearing on the expected result

Answer (score 0):

IIUC try slicing off the end of `df` based on the length of `df2` then [`append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html#pandas-dataframe-append):

```
df = df[:len(df) - len(df2)].append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```

`df`:

```
  user results
0    A    Rick
1    A  Patram
2    A    John
3    A   Peter
4    A    Anne
```

Or with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc):

```
df.loc[len(df) - len(df2):, :] = df2.values
```

`df`:

```
  user results
0    A    Rick
1    A  Patram
2    A    John
3    A   Peter
4    A    Anne
```